# Wordpress: "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons" when trying to upload standard image files

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, png, jpeg

Does anyone know of any workaround for this?

I'm trying to upload .jpg and .png files, both file types allowed in standard Wordpress settings, but I get the above error.

The workarounds I've googled so far don't work as Wordpress no longer sees the files i'm uploading as images. These are the plugin: Disable Real Mime Check, and variations of code that allow unfiltered uploads in the functions.php file.

I'm sometimes able to get my images uploaded but mostly not, and I can't see a pattern to which images get uploaded and which don't.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook `upload_mimes`.  See the detail explanation here.

https://www.uyond.com/resource/how-to-fix-upload-not-permitted-error-in-wordpress/

Answer (score -3):

You can try editing the wp-config.php file and adding in;

```
define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true);
```

This will allow you to then upload forbidden files, however as a precaution once uploaded I would delete this edit.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. I have tried similar code, as I explained above, but Wordpress then no longer saw the files as image files, and they didn't render on the webpage. :/