# How to upload PUB (or other octet-stream) files to WordPress when you can't allow unfiltered uploading

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, mime-types, mime

My current company wants to be able to upload Microsoft Publisher files to a password-protected page in WordPress. Verified the mime type is `application/octet-stream` and **not** `application/x-mspublisher` in the WordPress server's point of view.

I know we can globally disable format filtering in `wp-config.php` (as recommended here: [Wordpress: "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons" when trying to upload standard image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413005/wordpress-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons-when-tr)) like this:

```
define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true);
```

...but I'd really like to avoid that. That's a security nightmare asking to happen, imo.

I also know I could just disable format filtering on the staging copy, upload the files, and then reactivate it. I'm doing that for this time around. However, I want the team to be able to upload future Publisher files without needing developer intervention.

I tried this code in my child theme's `functions.php` file, and it still won't work.

```
function my_custom_upload_mimes($mimes = array()) {
    $mimes['pub'] = "application/octet-stream";
    return $mimes;
}

add_action('upload_mimes', 'my_custom_upload_mimes');
```

I also capitalized the key string to `$mimes['PUB']` and that didn't work either.

This is the error message I still get: `Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.`

Has anybody written the above code and figured out why it still didn't work?